# Prove that (x,y) = (x,Ay) for a given matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

So $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ I need to show that $(x,y)=(x,Ay)$.  I have worked out that $(x,Ay)= x_1(2y_1+y_2)+x_2(y_1+2y_2)$.  This does not equal the left side of my equality $x_1y_1+x_2y_2$.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd Attempt:

$$(x,y) = (x,Ay) \Rightarrow 2x_1y_1+2x_2y_2+x_1y_2+x_2y_1 = x_1y_1+x_2y_2$$
$$\Rightarrow x_1y_2 + x_2y_1 + x_1 y_1+x_2y_2 = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow (x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2)=0$$
This implies $x_1=-x_2$ or $y_1=-y_2$.

It seems like the thing you are trying to show is only true for certain values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I do mean the inner product.  So taking $(x,Ay)=(A^Tx,y)$ just rearranges the equation that I already got.  I don't see how that helps relate the entire thing to (x,y).

Comment: @Blackeyes please see the new solution above.